# How do I limit amounts of times a Discord command can be run for different people in Python

Tags: python, discord, bots

I want to restrict my Discord bot commands to only allow people to use a certain number of commands. It is python. I pasted what I have below where it restricts it to certain roles. Thanks for your help

```
@bot.command(name='command', help='')
@commands.has_any_role("bot", "non-bot")
async def maintenance(ctx):
    try:
        await ctx.message.delete()

        embed = discord.Embed(title='Title here',
                              description="Message here", color=0x6aa780)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    except Exception as e:
        print("maintenance command failed!")
        print(e)
```

Comment: You could use a database to track the number of times someone has used a command (successfully) and check if the user reach their quota.

Answer (score 0):

As a previous comment pointed out, storing successful commands is a good method for this.
Depending on what you are trying to do, you could either permanently store the commands or temporarily store them in a variable (for a small server).
To do this you will need a key for each user: the user id
Save the key in a database with a datafield for the command counter.

For example a temporary storage (since I am rushing this it may not be too efficient I hope others can correct it should I make any flaws):

commands_used_store = [] #It will be a list

```
def add_one_to_users_commands(userid): #Call every successful command
    global commands_used_store
    tempflag = False
    for x in range(len(commands_used_store)):
        if commands_used_store[x][0] == userid:
            commands_used_store[x][1] += 1
            tempflag = True
    if tempflag == False:
        commands_used_store.append([userid, 1])

def retrieve_commands_count(userid): #To retrieve the users commands count
    global commands_used_store
    for x in range(len(commands_used_store)):
        if commands_used_store[x][0] == userid:
            return commands_used_store[x][1]
```

To store it permanently id recommend finding a way to store data i.e. a file
This is just a method to temporarily store the values as an example, just retrieve the commands count for the user to check if they have used over 2 commands and if they have, send a message back saying they have overused it or something idk you do you.

P.S. By temporarily store the values I mean it will be stored until you stop running the program